# C++ Struct with default argument, optionally changeable in constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, optional-parameters, default-arguments

Let's say I have the following struct.

```
struct vehicle
{
  int    price;                           
  char*  year;                           
  char*  type; 
}
```

I would like to make a regular constructor for it, that would allow me to specify each member.

Nevertheless, I would like to set the member "type", as "car" by default, having only to specify the "type" in the constructor, in the not so often cases when the vehicle would not be a "car".

Comment: Aside: Is there any reason for the `char*`? A `std::string` would be easier to use.

Comment: It was just to simplify, the same question would be valid for the int member "price".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you didn't say it, but I sense a small misunderstanding: The difference between a struct and a class is just convention. Structs are classes in C++. The keywords `struct` and `class` can be used to declare a class and the only difference is the default access (in accordance with the common convention that structs have all public).

That out of the way, you can simply write two constructors (i am using `std::string` for strings, because I find c-strings extremely difficult to work with):

```
struct vehicle
{
  int price;                           
  std::string year;                           
  std::string type; 
  vehicle(int p, const std::string& y, const std::string& t) : price(p),year(y),type(t) {}
  vehicle(int p, const std::string& y) : price(p),year(y),type("car") {}
};
```

You can also use in class initializer (they came with C++11):

```
struct vehicle
{
  int price;                           
  std::string year;                           
  std::string type{"car"}; 
  vehicle(int p, const std::string& y, const std::string& t) : price(p),year(y),type(t) {}
  vehicle(int p, const std::string& y) : price(p),year(y) {}
};
```

The initializer list on the constructor wins over the in class initializer, and in the second constructor the in class initializer is used.

Comment: What about if I would like to not use constructors? I would initialise the members as you did in example 2, assigning {"car"} to member "type" and then when I would instantiate the structure itself how could I do? I tried struct vehicle veh = {2000, "2018"} , but it wouldn't work. Do you know any reliable alternative?

Comment: @pbl why would it not work? Looks fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/bvWVwH

Comment: @pbl or if you like without constructors https://godbolt.org/z/3R7k8g

Comment: I just realised my problem was because I was trying to do the default assignment to a member which was not the last on the structure's order (e.g "year" in this struct). It's a shame that you can only use the last argument for the default values.